# Argon2 confusion when computing J_1 and J_2

Tags: password-hashing, argon2

I'm implementing Argon2id from the RFC 9106 and I'm at the part where each thread computes J_1 and J_2 in order to generate indices [l] and [z].

I'm confused as to which TYPE (y = 0, 1 or 2) of Argon2 to use when computing J_1 and J_2, because the RFC basically says:

"If you're doing Argon2id, compute J_1 and J_2 as described for Argon2i if pass number r = 0 and slice number ls = 0 or 1."

The confusion I have is that Argon2i uses the version number y to compute J_1 and J_2.

But since we're doing Argon2id and the steps say to compute J_1 and J_2 "as if it was Argon2i", which version of Argon2 do we use here? For 2i or for 2id?